# Count the number of messages for specific user jda

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have found a lot of tutorials on how to count the number of messages for a specific user but all of them was for discord.py. Now I need to do it but for discord jda. I have tried a lot of different methods but non worked. Any help?

okay this is what I tried so far. Even though I know it is so wrong anyways:

```
public class ExpSystem extends ListenerAdapter {

    HashMap<User, Integer> playerXp = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<User, Integer> playerMessages = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<User, Integer> playerTimer = new HashMap<>();
    int counter = 0;
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event){
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        String command = args[0];
        System.out.println(event.getMessage());



        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("tr!" + "xp")){
            System.out.println("command");
            if (canGetXp(event.getMember().getUser())){
                if (event.getMember().getUser() == event.getMessage().getMember().getUser()){
                    counter ++;
                    setPlayerMessages(event.getMember().getUser(),counter);
                    System.out.println("cangetxp");
                    randXp(event.getMember().getUser());
                    setPlayerTime(event.getMember().getUser(), 3);
                    event.getChannel().sendMessage("You have " + getPlayerXp(event.getMember().getUser()) + " xp"+ "And " + getPlayerMessages(event.getMember().getUser()) + " Messages").queue();
                }

            }else {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("You have " + getPlayerXp(event.getMember().getUser()) + " xp" + "And " + getPlayerMessages(event.getMember().getUser()) + " Messages").queue();
            }

        }


    }

    private int getPlayerXp(User member){
        return playerXp.get(member);
    }

    private int getPlayerMessages(User member){
        return playerMessages.get(member);
    }

    private void setPlayerXp(User member, int num){
        playerXp.put(member, num);
    }

    private void setPlayerMessages(User member, int num){
        playerXp.put(member, num);
    }

    private int getPlayerTime(User member){
        return playerTimer.get(member);
    }

    private void setPlayerTime(User member, int num){
        playerTimer.put(member,num);
    }

    private void randXp(User member){
        Random r = new Random();
        if (!playerXp.containsKey(member)){
          setPlayerXp(member, 0);
        }
        setPlayerXp(member, getPlayerXp(member) + r.nextInt(25));
    }

    private boolean canGetXp(User member){
        if(!playerTimer.containsKey(member)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void startTimer(){
        System.out.println("TIMER STARTED");
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (User member : playerTimer.keySet()){

                    setPlayerTime(member,getPlayerTime(member) - 1);
                    if (getPlayerTime(member) == 0){
                        playerTimer.remove(member);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task,1000,1000);
    }



}
```

My goal here is to gain xp when you send messages. But I always get:

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.util.HashMap.get(Object)" is null
    at ExpSystem.getPlayerMessages(ExpSystem.java:50)
    at ExpSystem.onGuildMessageReceived(ExpSystem.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:405)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:149)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:97)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:952)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:839)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:817)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:990)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

**EDIT**:
I have replaced  `playerXp.put(member, num);`
to  `platerMessages.put(member, num);` in the `setPlayerMessages` method.
But now the counter of all the users are the same, so it gives them the same number of messages. Is there any way I can Fix that?

Comment: Please update your question and include things that you've tried and also include output or error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually never put anything into `playerMessages` map.
Replace

```
private void setPlayerMessages(User member, int num){
        playerXp.put(member, num);
}
```

with

```
private void setPlayerMessages(User member, int num){
        playerMessages.put(member, num);
}
```

Comment: Okay, It kinda works now. but if another user types the same command it gives him the same number of messaegs as the first person. Is there any way the two could have separate counters?

Comment: you are passing counter with every setPlayerMessage and it is increased for every member. Instead of passing counter, you can set map value to 0 while putting entry in the map and then you count up on every call.